# Uniform Distribution Problem

Tags: uniform-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, and let $Y$ be a RV uniformly distributed in $[X,1]$. I want to calculate the theoretical distribution of $Y$, any hints? I already tried with simulation, which gave me an idea of what $Y$ looks like, but nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try a conditioning argument: for $0<y<1$
\begin{align}
   P[Y \leq y]
&= {\bf E}[ P[Y \leq y \mid X]] \\
&= {\bf E}\left[ \frac{y-X}{1-X} I_{[X \leq y]} \right] \\
&= \int_0^y \frac{y-x}{1-x}dx \\
&= \left. -(y-1)\ln(1-x) + x \right|^y_0 \\
&= -(y-1)\ln(1-y) + y.
\end{align}

Comment: Simulation confirmed this solution as well. Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 2):

$$P(Y<y)=\int_x P(Y<y|X=x) P(X=x) dx=\int_0^y \frac{y-x}{1-x} dx=[(1-y)\ln(1-x)+x]_{x=0}^{x=y}=(1-y)\ln(1-y)+y,$$
so the density function is its derivative $f_Y(y)=-\ln(1-y)$ for $y\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Ah, I see I was not fast enough :)